# SVN and VSS sync

Tags: svn, scripting, repository, visual-sourcesafe, synchronization

Can I sync files from SVN to VSS automatically?. My personal repository is SVN and my client hava a VSS repository. I'll would to like sync the repository throught scripts or something like that.

Can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know of no software to automate such a process, but you can put one together by taking advantage of SVN post-commit hooks (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) and the VSS command-line interface ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asxkfzy4(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asxkfzy4%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

The trickiest problems will likely be the addition/deletion/renaming of files in your SVN repository and reflecting those changes in VSS.  If the source in VSS can also change on you (by another developer), that's going to open a whole other can of worms - you'll have to manage the code in both directions, including merging.

Good luck.